How to logically formalize two-player with imperfect information?
It is known that any first-order formula with no free variables is equivalent to a perfect information game with finitely-many turns, that is, for example, the formula
$\forall x, \exists y, x\neq y$
describes the game « Alice plays $x$ first, and then, Bob, knowing that Alice played $x$, plays $y$, and then the referee checks if $x\neq y$, and if so, Bob wins.
Moreover, any strategy for the $\exists$-player gives a proof of the formula, and vice-versa (this might depend on some form of the axiom of choice, since it might involve skolemization, but I don’t think this subtlety is relevant here).
My question is: how can we deal with games where both Alice and Bob secretly make choices of some moves that they will play at some point of the game, they commit to their choices by making a promise to the referee, that will check during the game if Alice and Bob play according to their choice (if not, they lose because they are cheating)? Equivalently, to which logical things are these games isomorphic?

Leon Henkin introduced branching quantifiers that can model these situations.
In ordinary first-order formulas, the dependence of the quantified variables forms a linear order, with each variable depending only on the choices of the preceding ones.  When branching quantifiers are allowed, the dependence can be a general partial order.
For example, one might have a formula with four variables $x, x', y, y'$ in which the choices of both $y$ and $y'$ depend on both of $x$ and $x'$, but neither $y$ nor $y'$ depends on the other, and neither $x$ nor $x'$ depends on the other.
In the game semantics this models a situation in which two players $P$ and $P'$ make simultaneous hidden moves $x$ and $x'$.  After these are revealed, the players make new moves $y$ and $y'$.
The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy has an article on "Logic and Games" which has a section that discusses this.
